# Weird behavior with <select> and DOM injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, mootools

I found a crazy bug tested with both jQuery 1.10.2 and MooTools 1.4.5. Saw on Firefox 22 MacOSX Lion.

I have a page wrapped in a `<form>` and a bug happen when trying to include a `<select>` tag without a `<form>` tag in DOM : if you refresh the page, input radios buttons values change and both last text inputs value are reset.

I've created a little page who reproduce the problem (can't add it on jsfiddle because we need the native browser refresh on forms to see what happening) : http://www.apixelife.com/stackoverflow/refresh-form-bug.html

I fixed it but my problem is that i already have a `<form>` in that page, and i need it here. Why can't we inject a `<select>` without firing this kind of bug after refresh ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you describe how to reproduce this step-by-step? I’m not seeing anything strange.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just doing a 'hard refresh'

Comment: @minitech you need firstable to test on Firefox (i'm on v22), then select the first radio button from the first `<div>` and the second radio button from the second `<div>`. Then add number in each texts boxes, (between 1 - 10). You will see the `<select>`DOM injection. After that just press F5. (no hard-refresh)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP nop, just a F5 refresh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this issue has been fixed on Firefox.